# ¿Como mostrar una gran cantidad de datos en una tabla con JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Buen día a todos, tengo un problema, debo mostrar aproximadamente entre 30 y 40 mil registros en una tabla jquery datatables, hago una consulta con PHP, para después poder exportar a excel, pero me aparece el error que adjunto en la imagen. Gracias, espero me puedan apoyar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te quedaste sin memoria.. ponele mas memoria al proceso...

Comment: Hace varios años tuve un problema similar, resulta que eliminé todos los filtros y lógica para mostrar solo una tabla html pura, al hacer esto me di cuenta que pasadas las 20mil filas el rendimiento era deplorable, con ordenadores más nuevos y mejores navegadores quizás hoy se puede superar esa cifra, pero siempre existe un límite en el que el navegador puede renderizar html. Si a eso le sumas que ocupas datatable y jquery, que precisamente no brillan por su performance, es que sencillamente no se puede. Lo mejor es mostrar la tabla paginada

Comment: "Out of memory" es un mensaje bastante claro. Cuando se trata de decenas de miles de líneas, es una cantidad demasiado grande para pretender enviar el listado completo al navegador, y también para exportarlas a un archivo en un solo proceso, aquí entras en problemas de rendimiento, y el uso memoria es sólo uno de ellos. Para exportar es recomendable que lo hagas por lotes, en vez de en un único proceso. Para mostrar el listado completo en el navegador, no tengo claro que realmente quieras hacerlo, pero la solución también sería partir, haciendo por ejemplo solicitudes AJAX al hacer scroll.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tenes que usar server side processing con una datatable de ese tamaño

Answer (score 0):

la cantidad de datos que estas intentando mostrar son demasiados yo te recomendaria buscar la manera de exportarlos en partes o desarrollar la logica para que se puedan ir mostrando cada vez que scrolles hacia abajo, podrías usar AJAX y Query para eso, un saludo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getData.php',
            data:'id='+lastID,
            beforeSend:function(html){
                $('.load-more').show();
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('.load-more').remove();
                $('#postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});